# XML file to POST and send data back to a batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

i am a very new user when it comes to this. i have tried out multiple google pages to try and understand how to do this, but have failed.

I am trying to create a batch file to run a program with a few parameters filled in, but with getting one parameter it requires a token, which is recieved in HTTP.
What i have found i need to do (correct me if i'm wrong) is that i run a XML file (also sending some data to the xml file from the batch file) from the batch file , and send back a certain part ('token') to the batch file.

I am not sure what to put in the batch to actually run the xml file, or what to put to get the data back from it.

The http request header :

```
POST /api/login/ HTTP/1.1 
Host: toontowninfinite.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and i want the request data to be

```
n=<username i specify in the batch file>&p=<password i specify in the batch file>&dist=test
```

then the thing it copies back would be the token field here

```
{"success":true,"token":"<mytoken-confidential>"}
```

Thanks for any help given

Comment: can anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat).It uses winhttp request object that should be faster than
Msxml2.XMLHTTP as there is no dom parsing of the response.It is capable to do requests with body and all http methods.

```
call winhttpjs.bat  http://somelink.com/something.html -saveTo c:\something.html -header hdrs.txt
```